# How to Run A DB Sync Server On Daedalus?

Tags: cardano-node, daedalus, cardano-db-sync, blockfrost

So I have been trying to do some fun things with Daedalus, and realised I should be able to query the node from it. This makes me wonder how to set up a limited database / querying system for my own needs out of Daedalus? Kinda like a smaller blockfrost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node by itself is stripped down of resources to keep active records of history, so the expectation that you could query node from Daedalus to have similar capability as cardano-db-sync (which maintains kinda everything from chain, as well as from ledger events, alongwith historical view). Thus, the resource requirements from dbsync are expected to be much more.

DB Sync v13 will allow you to stop querying ledger-state data which will shave off ~8-10GB (at the expense of not saving off-chain calcs coming from ledger-state). Instead if you're after creating small-scoped utility while not being able to spend much resources, you can look at projects below:

1. [Ogmios](https://ogmios.dev) / [Kupo](https://github.com/CardanoSolutions/kupo)
2. [Oura](https://github.com/txpipe/oura) / [Scrolls](https://github.com/txpipe/scrolls)

Of course - the more you want to store and manage historically, higher the resources required will be

Answer (score 0):

You can run [cardano-db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync), but be aware that is a rather heavy weight application that requires lots of RAM (ie 32 Gig) and will take about a week to sync.

Comment: 32 GB will not be enough if you are also running cardano-node on the same machine. Or you will need to add a lot of swap...

Comment: Yeah looked at the repo this is not a viable option, for my computer and its over speced to train AI. That means I Have more Storage and RAM then most people.

Comment: @George-APEXStakePool I run a `node` and `db-sync` in a VM with 18 Gugabytes (16 was not enough).

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo If you run it long enough, you will see that one of them will eventually be killed with OOM error. It happened to me last week on a VM with 32 GM RAM. I upgraded it to 40 GB RAM and I also increased the swap (which was only 4 GB).